# It's only your opinion because you don't know the answer

Tags: discussion, down-votes, close-reasons

I've had this problem a few times and it is becoming noisome.

One form is:

1. A question is asked, readers do not know the answer and because of the type of question, invoke the "It's a matter of opinion" clause and mark it down/mark it for close.

   The example which prompted this was my question to SO "Why do games developers use VS2005 RT instead of more recent versions". I found a game development SE site after having half a dozen people invoke 1) above and there got the actual answer in a matter of seconds.

   A second example which shows a subtly different application of the same faulty logic is as follows:
2. A question is asked, readers fail basic reading comprehension and mark down/mark for close for the wrong reason.

   I asked "Which Java IDE is prevalent in bank development teams?". Because this looks like "Which is the best IDE", some people invoked 2). If you read the question and give it two seconds thought, you could answer the question definitively by either polling all the banks and working out which was most popular, or less definitively, as I was attempting to do, ask people who have made a career in banks doing Java.

   Finally version 3:
3. A question is asked trying to establish the differences, primarily the strengths and weaknesses of several competing options. A user almost accurately identifies this as opinion-based and shuts down the question.

   This one is harder; as an example, I once asked if anyone had done a comparison of the control suites available. Here's the problem, while the results are almost certainly going to involve some degree of opinion (I found syncfusion confusing and infragistics overly complicated), there is nowhere else to get this sort of comparative information except from the mouth of one who has done the comparison. It is hugely valuable.

   Part of my solution involves taking an overly cautious approach to asking the question, with as many warnings and explanations as possible to head off the less helpful, but this makes the question longer than it needs to be, and I don't believe these people are the sort likely to read beyond the title anyway.

My options currently are to stop asking questions that have useful (to me) answers, to carry on asking and getting infuriated, or a third option I'm rather hoping you can fill in.

Comment: It sounds like all of the questions you asked aren't suitable for the Stack Exchange family of sites.

Comment: "It's only your opinion because you don't know the answer."  Probably not the best way to start off a question...

Comment: As George says, those all sound off-topic or similar.  Question 1 could potentially be constructed better; if you were to ask a more pointed question that got directly at what you really wanted to know - if there was some specific issue that caused VS2005 to be preferable - it might be on topic, but even then, probably not.  Question 2, you admit your intent is to poll people; that is very much not what SO/SE is about.  Post that question on a web forum or somesuch.  Question 3 is also inappropriate for a similar reason.

Comment: #2 and #3 are both just opinion polls.

Comment: To close 3 of your question will have taken 15 very experienced people. Possibly at least consider that they might have a point, doesnt that seem more likely than all 15 having no idea what they're doing

Comment: @RichardTingle It takes 5 people (or 1 mod) not 15.  People can vote on more than one question...

Comment: @Servy im multipling 3 questions by 5 votes each. If its a mod they're even more experienced but yes that is true. Of course there could be overlaps but there are a lot of people on SO, mods asside I doubt theres much overlap

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes, I understand how you got the number.  I'm saying it's not correct.  5 people can each vote on 3 different questions.  Perhaps they didn't, I can't know without seeing the questions.  The number of people involved is somewhere between 1 and 15.  15 is the max, not the min.  You said it was the min.

Comment: @Servy technically I said it was the number, not the minimum. The average is probably around 14. This is hardly important, my point is consider what people are saying. Please for the love of god don't debate if 14 really is the average

Comment: @RichardTingle 13, surely.

Comment: And while I'm on it, the gamedev title was edited and is now not the question I asked. It's tangential, and makes a bunch of assumptions I didn't with the original question. Moderation gone mental.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, so I downvoted it. (Oh, also, VS 2005 is the last version that will target Windows 9x. That's one reason why people might use it. That's why I've used it for a project. Which is just evidence that all the answers to your first question are merely speculative. You'll have to ask the game developers who do why they use VS 2005. Each will probably have a different answer. Thus, "matter of opinion".)

Comment: Cheers Cody, that's sort of the point. Why on earth would you downvote something because you don't know the answer? Also I did ask in GameDev and they provided an answer. It was opinion in the sense that you can't derive some mathamatic proof of its veracity, but if you asked 20 pro game devs the same question I'd put money on all agreeing with the given answer, perhaps expanding on it in places.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It sounds like all of the questions you asked aren't suitable for the Stack Exchange family of sites.

I'm going to assume good faith here and attempt to answer the question you've asked. To do so, I need to look into your deleted questions.

[For your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731193/why-do-so-many-windows-games-rely-on-vc-2005-runtime), this is what you asked:

> It's Steam summer sale time and I've been installing a few new games.
>   I've noticed than most have a prerequisite of the Visual C++ 2005
>   runtime.
>
> I'm sure I've seen 2008 pop up a few times, so my question is why are
>   so many games dependent on the 2005 RT?
>
> Before the downvotes drown me, I mean 2005 as opposed to something
>   released in the intervening 8 years. I know why C++ is used.
>
> EDIT: It's only your opinion because you don't know the answer.
>
> Edit2: Stuff it, I've asked on GameDev.

Your later edits (Edits2 and Edits3) only compounded the problem.

[You tried again on Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59382/vc-2005-rt-preference-in-games), and asked a pretty decent question (although I'm still not sure it's appropriate for Stack Exchange -- but that's Game Dev's call, not mine):

> I understand why C++ is used. That is not what this question is about.
>
> When I install games, commonly Steam (I pretty much only use Steam
>   these days) will install the 2005 RT.
>
> My question is why is this the case? What is the reason a runtime
>   released over 8 years ago is still prevalent? Some of the games I've
>   installed recently are slightly older, so assuming a couple of years
>   dev time you could make the case it was the tried and tested standard
>   at the time.
>
> I've asked this on stack overflow, but a lot of people don't know the
>   answer therefore assume it's opinion. I'd assert if you do work in
>   games you'll know of an actual answer, perhaps several.

Your second try at asking this question did a much better job of:

1. Not inflaming the crowd
2. Giving insight into the reasoning for the question
3. Not telling people to 'stuff it'

You're still making the mistake of thinking that people who "don't know the answer assume [any answer] is opinion."

Your [second](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197832/which-java-ide-if-any-is-preferred-mandated-for-professional-developers) and third questions are just off topic for any Stack Exchange site. It may be a question, and it may be programming related, but we've explicitly disallowed such questions. You may disagree with this, but that's the way things are.

I hate to say this, but it sounds like you don't realize that Stack Exchange is not meant for opinion based questions. One of our close reasons was recently reworded and now reads as such:

> **primarily opinion-based** -  Many good questions generate some degree of
>   opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will
>   tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts,
>   references, or specific expertise.

Of course, [that could just be, like, my opinion, man](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWdd6_ZxX8c).

Comment: Haha, I'd give it to you that he might not have inflamed the Gamedev crowd on his second try, but if you've got to make another community look like idiots as part of your question, you're arguably still doing something wrong. And I have to say I'm somewhat surprised this lasted on Gamedev.

Comment: @Bart Yea; I'm not a fan of the way he asked the question on Game Dev, but each community is different. I edited the question, but I wasn't logged in at the time. I'm not used to the Stack Exchange global login not carrying over to another site.

Comment: @George I'll go with your answer, as it seems clear that is what the community wants. I wasn't trying to wind up SO, but I'm not going to pussyfoot about when it's clear the moderation has gone to some peoples heads. I was actually being honest with the GameDev people, I've asked the question elsewhere, they can go look it up, see what's going on. It's just courtesy. Plus they gave me a sensible answer which might seem utterly banal, obvious, tedious and meaningless to some, but I'm asking for me, not as a sop to others egos.

Comment: @Ian And yet SE doesn't exist to help you.  It exists to create a useful repository of knowledge that is there to help the worldwide community as a whole; if it helps some individuals asking questions that's just an added side benefit, not a guiding principle.  Not being rude and avoiding insulting a community that you're in the process of asking for help isn't pussyfotting, it's just common sense/curtsy.  The comments George is referring to are not only offtopic and inappropriate, but in no way help you to get an answer (and in fact have hurt you quite a bit).

Comment: @Servy, That's sounds like an opinion to me ;) Anyway, forget it. I'll continue asking questions and if the "community" deem then unworthy, I'll just swear under my breath, reflect on how those who can do and those who can't moderate, and happpily delete it and move on with my life.

Comment: @Ian It's not an opinion.  The founders of the site have said it *many* times.  It is the founding principle of the site.  It is fact.

Comment: I won't rise to it. Good luck Servy.

Answer (score 17):

> "Why do games developers use VS2005 RT instead of more recent versions".

That immediately begs the question "do they"? And even if so, you're only going to get best guesses or anecdotal answers. Possibly with a whole host of users chiming in, one not more correct than the other. "No, we always use the latest IDE on our AAA games", "We have a lot of legacy code to deal with", "The costs are prohibitive for us to update", etc. Not a great fit for Stack Overflow. If you managed to get this answered somewhere else, good for you, but it's not a great question.

> "Which Java IDE is prevalent in bank development teams?". ...you could answer the question definitively by either polling all the banks and working out which was most popular, or less definitively, as I was attempting to do, ask people who have made a career in banks doing java.

You have pretty much answered this one yourself. You're asking a polling question. And we don't do those. They are by definition off-topic. They are unlikely to ever lead to a definitive answers and far more likely to see plenty of users chime in with their view or particular situation.

> A question is asked trying to establish the differences, primarily the strengths and weaknesses of several competing options.

Once again that's a poll. Or perhaps even a recommendation question. And we don't do those on Stack Overflow. Sites like http://slant.co are perhaps a better fit for such questions.

All in all the closures seem reasonable based on your description of the questions. So instead of getting infuriated, it might be better to get a more full understanding of what is and isn't appropriate for the site. That will make participating a whole lot easier and enjoyable.

Comment: I disagree on your analysis of the third.  It's not always a poll or recommendation.  Comparing two different things is something that can, in some cases, even make up a great question.  For example, "Here is are two code snippets, under what circumstances is A better, and when is B better."  (Assuming the question contained some initial analysis and some scope narrowing as well.)

Comment: @Servy without seeing the actual question I'd hazard a guess that such initial analysis and narrow scope was absent. But I'll admit that a sufficiently narrow scoped situation might fare better. Then again, it might not.

Comment: For that reason I think that the most likely problem with such questions is that they're too broad, rather than saying that they're polling/opinion based/recommendations.  Much like self answered questions, they're allowed, but just very very hard to do *well*.

Comment: In fact, I've yet to see such a question done truly well @Servy. My "poll" or "opinion" view of them is mainly based on the answers it's likely to invite though. I'll admit that. A truly correct answer would indeed lead to the question being too broad.

Comment: I disagree with much of what you've said. You've missed the point on all three. Too much to rebut in a comment, but take number two. Which Java IDE is prevalent. It is not a poll. Read the question and you will see it has a specific, measurably correct answer. If 20 out of 25 banks use Eclipse, the answer is Eclipse. It isn't feasible to poll all the banks, but I'd expect a senior dev in my industry to have worked in enough to be able to say whether there is or is not a preferred choice.

Answer (score 9):

1. "and got the actual answer in a matter of seconds" No, you got someone's opinion within several seconds.  You didn't get a definitive answer.  That was what you wanted, but it doesn't change the fact that such questions don't belong on the site.
2. You are correct in that this isn't an opinion question.  It has an objective answer, however, it's not a practical programming problem.  It's a polling problem.  In fact, it's not even a problem.  Knowing what's prevalent doesn't help you solve any problems, it's just a random fact.  Knowing which IDE you should use is a problem you might have, but that question would be inappropriate here for entirely different reasons.  If this question wasn't closed as "off topic" it probably should have been.  If your concern is that questions are being closed for the wrong reasons, even if they should be closed, then by all means bring it up (we should fix it) but don't expect people to get *too* worked up about it.  As long as the right stuff is being closed that's what's most important.
3. Sometimes these *are* opinion based, and sometimes they aren't.  Often these questions are "too broad".  A complete analysis is often of too large of a scope for an SO question.  I wouldn't go so far as to say all strength/weakness questions don't belong here, but I find that, in actual practice, a very high percentage of them don't (not always for the same reasons though).  If you linked to a specific question we could discuss if, and if so, why, this question isn't appropriate.

Comment: 1) You're confusing opinion with experience. It's like arguing about climate change. Actually thinking about it, a more useful answer if there isn't one would have been "There is no specific reason". 

2) You've made an assumption that it won't help me solve a problem. That's a tad egocentric. I wasn't asking to enlighten you, I had a specific need at the time.

3) Agreed, my complaint is the moderation doesn't make the judgement call well.

Comment: @Ian 1) You asked the question of why, in general, this is done.  An answer that states only a particular person's situation is fact about them, but it's only an opinion as to the general case; they aren't speaking to anyone else.  If you're only interested in a bunch of individual stories, and not the general case, then it's inappropriate for different reasons, as others have discussed.  2) If there is an actual problem being solved, you haven't stated what it is, which is enough for my argument to apply.  3) The site is community moderated, and it seems your question wasn't different..