# Don't close opinion-based questions, but have them protected from being answered by untrusted users

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, protected-questions

Happened to me a few times: I needed to determine which solution is better so first I googled for a while and found nothing trustful. So I asked on Stack Overflow because research takes a long time.

As a result, my question was closed because it was opinion-based, but I've been doing research and found a result. I wanted to post it but I couldn't, so now I'm waiting for my question to be reopened.

A good example would be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449200/send-to-recycle-bin-vs-erase). I got an answer from another user – quick research showed that the answer wasn't completely right, but more research showed that the answer was 100% correct.

I've seen more good questions closed as "opinion-based". I think it would be better not to close such a questions but protect them from untrusted users. I'm not talking about protection at a 10 reputation limit – in such a situation the limit should be, I think 1k, because answering such a question requires lots of knowledge and work experience.

**EDIT**  I do not say, that those question, that are much likely opinion based stay. Lets say question "What is better C++ or JAVA" is clearly opinion based so it should be closed. But those which requires deep knowledge in some specific parts of system e.g. filesystem, compiler optimizations etc. would be protecting.

Comment: Fact is that we don't deal in opinions. This is explicitly stated in the Help Center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask So yeah, it's valid close reason and in fact a default close vote type.

Comment: "_So I asked in StackOverflow because research takes long time._" StackOverflow is not designed to be your research assistant. You should do your own research, try to implement what you can find, and ask only if you cannot find the answer elsewhere (as long as your question meets the other posted guidelines).

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I spend 3 days to make a research. If someone knows the answer then time is saving. So it is the reason of asking.

Comment: @Bart I know what king of questions shouldn't be asked but some question closed because of this are really valid because it is possible to get trusted answer after research.

Comment: If the question you linked us to has three days of research behind it, it clearly doesn't show that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you're still asking for opinions, they are not. If your question was wrongly closed, you can always appeal it. But it's up to you to do the research. We won't do research for you.

Comment: @slhck As I said I had to do research anyway because only one person asked. And sometimes looking in the internet helps to save time skipping researches for some parts of project.

Comment: @Bart In my opinion questions that have valid answer is not opinion based, just most people don't know what answer. And about reopening, when I got full results I nominated it for reopening but nothing happens, anyway, I'm not about reopening it. And about researches, I know what I have to do research but in many cases some people did that already, so if they can share results it would be better for more people.

Comment: Someone argued before that [it's only opinion because you don't know the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189409/its-only-your-opinion-because-you-dont-know-the-answer). The question you link I might not have closed for being to susceptible to opinions though. It's just a poor question showing no focus, and no effort.

Comment: You just asked it the wrong way.  A "which is better" question requires carefully describing the circumstances.  Which you did not do.  You certainly made it worse by giving a completely unlikely usage scenario which made it very clear that you never even tried it by yourself.  SO users are expected to research the problem before they ask.  If you had done so then you'd never have asked the question.  You'd be ahead if you simply asked for the *difference* between the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact of the matter is that Stack Exchange isn't built to deal in opinions. The system is made to answer questions which have a definite right and wrong answer.

Also, if this were implemented (which I am strongly against), the rep limit would need to be raised *considerably*. I am 6k here, 4k on SO. Therefore, even *I* would fall into the able-to-answer-subjective-questions category. If the system allows me to do that, it's not good

Comment: My offered 1k rep was just an example, it is too much. But some questions really need to be protected from whose who don't know what are talking and 10 rep is not enough. Going back to my question. I edited it a bit and added necessary information.

Comment: @user2623967 so a really smart person who comes and joins this site is not allowed to answer your opinion-based question? Does reputation really prove how smart someone is, or how much time they've spent here? I don't think the latter really makes them any more capable of supplying an opinion than the former.