# Reputation shouldn't be shown close to username on questions and answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

Hi I've been looking through SO and found some highly voted question what shouldn't be there. Example would be [What's your most controversial programming opinion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion) or [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered) ATM they are closed but they've been opened for a long time. Also I've seen more similar type question, what are also shouldn't be asked at SO and those questions were downvoted and closed, as I looked these was asked by users with low reputation.

Same situations with answers. I've seen answers with unusual (but well working) way of solving problems. Those that were offered by user with high reputation is upvoted, those offered by users with low reputation downvoted.

It looks like users before flagging or downvoting question/answer look at reputation and if it is high enough decide not to do that, but if it low, they do.

Avoid such situations is impossible but I think that reputation should only be shown in user profile, because it would let to prevent some kind of discrimination of users with lower reputation and some kind of exaltation those who have high reputation.

Comment: In context with this [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190690/dont-close-opinion-based-questions-but-have-them-protected-from-being-answered) of you, I'd support above question.

Comment: Just to confirm, you think there is a correlation between voting and open/closed status, and because of that you think reputation should be less predominately displayed?

Comment: @psubsee2003 more or less but but I think that.

Comment: This is nonsense. High-rep users' off-topic questions get closed much more quickly and brutally because the assumption is they should know better.

Comment: It's not total nonsense.  I've been tempted to downvote answers, and then after seeing the posters' reputations decided not to because with a value like that perhaps they know something significant that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've been looking through SO and found some highly voted question what shouldn't be there. Example would be [What's your most controversial programming opinion?(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion) or [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered) ATM they are closed but they've been opened for a long time. Also I've seen more similar type question, what are also shouldn't be asked at SO and those questions were downvoted and closed, as I looked these was asked by users with low reputation.

You must have missed the *dates* on these questions. It has nothing to do with the reputation of the users who asked them. In fact, because of their age, the users who asked them probably had a fairly low reputation score at the time they posted the questions. The scope of the site has changed significantly since it was first founded, and experience has forced us to tighten up our requirements. What you're seeing is merely the effects of that: the types of questions that people *used* to be able to get away with asking are now unceremoniously rejected.

Heck, we even made it painfully obvious that those questions you linked to are no longer valid or acceptable questions on the site. There are banners everywhere, the vote arrows are removed, and you can't do anything (like post a new answer, edit existing posts, etc.). The questions are effectively "frozen in time", like a curiosity of an ancient civilization in a museum. What more do you want us to do?

But the fundamental point is that it doesn't matter *who* asks those questions. If [any one of these people](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) posted a question tomorrow that asked for the best comment ever encountered in source code, or the most useful C# extension method, or everyone's favorite methods for dealing with a Dilbert boss, it would be nearly instantly closed, too. And downvoted. Probably *more heavily* downvoted, since everyone would expect them to know better. They don't post these questions, of course, because they *do* know better.

The [requirements for questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [guidelines on what types of questions *not* to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) are all stated clearly in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). There should be no confusion on what is acceptable, and these rules apply equally to *all* users.

Aside from the date issue, what you're seeing is merely an issue of confirmation bias. Basically, the users who are least likely to know and/or follow our guidelines are new users with low reputation scores. So these are the people whose questions are most likely to be downvoted and/or closed. But it is invalid to assume it is *because* they're new users. You're confusing correlation with causality. And inverting that relationship to boot.

> Same situations with answers. I've seen answers with unusual (but well working) way of solving problems. Those that were offered by user with high reputation is upvoted, those offered by users with low reputation downvoted.

There are also rules for answers in the Help Center: [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [what types of answers should not be posted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Again, these apply equally to all users, regardless of reputation.

But "unusual" methods of solving problems are perfectly valid answers, *especially* if they work. These can be upvoted no matter who posts them.

What you're probably seeing is explained by limited knowledge or understanding of the problem domain. Inexperienced users (measured not necessarily by reputation on the site, but by their experience with a particular programming language or technology) might try to post "clever" or "unusual" answers, but get some important details wrong. Although neither you nor they understand these details and why they make their answer wrong (which is totally okay, of course, not everyone knows everything), we have a lot of real geniuses participating on the site who will understand why they are wrong. They're also sticklers for detail and will downvote wrong answers. Often, they'll even leave a comment explaining why it is wrong. This is what makes Stack Overflow great—good answers that are vetted by people even smarter or more experienced than you to ensure that they're even better.

If you think I'm wrong, I challenge you to provide some links to examples.

> It looks like users before flagging or downvoting question/answer look at reputation and if it is high enough decide not to do that, but if it low, they do.

*Some* people might do this, but I do not think that it is very common. The people who *do* do that probably should not be doing it.

As I mentioned above, our rules and guidelines are pretty clear and apply equally to all users. If a post does not conform with them, it should be flagged, regardless of who posted it.

I suppose that sometimes users with a high reputation are granted *the benefit of the doubt*, but I hardly see how that's a bad thing. Not only does their reputation score indicate extensive experience with the site and what is acceptable, but it also makes it more likely that they're talking about something that goes over your head and you're misunderstanding what they're actually saying. That said, there's nothing wrong with voicing your concerns to them in a comment. They'll either explain what they are thinking, or they'll realize that they've screwed up and remove their content. Either way, it is a net win.

> Avoid such situations is impossible but I think that reputation should only be shown in user profile, because it would let to prevent some kind of discrimination of users with lower reputation and some kind of exaltation those who have high reputation.

Even if what you're saying is true (and I've discussed above why I don't think it is), this isn't a very good solution. The user name (which links to the profile) will still be shown next to all of their contributions, and it would just take one click to figure out what that person's reputation score is. Often, the reputation is even available in a tooltip if you hover over someone's name. So if someone wanted to make biased decisions, this still wouldn't stop them.

Comment: tldr, but upvoted nonetheless, because of the high rep.

Comment: Upvoted because Cody is part of our elite boys' club. We take care of each other, right?

Answer (score 3):

You suspect that there is a correlation between existing votes and pending vote activity, but you provide nothing to validate your suspicion. The questions you used as examples are very bad examples ([note that one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/406760/1) was asked by Jon Skeet) because they date from a time when (question) standards and behaviour was markedly different to what it is now.

> Same situations with answers. I've seen answers with unusual (but well working) way of solving problems. Those that were offered by user with high reputation is upvoted, those offered by users with low reputation downvoted.

This normally occurs because high rep users (usually) submit higher quality answers. If a user submits a low quality answer then it should be down voted regardless of the repuation they have.

> It looks like users before flagging or downvoting question/answer look at reputation and if it is high enough decide not to do that, but if it low, they do.

Once again, provide some actual examples.

Answer (score -3):

I support this suggestion, but not because of possible biases in question/answer voting, choosing accepted answers, and closing off-topic. Rather, showing reputation and badges everywhere provokes constant social comparison (and ego indulgence, I think, if you have a really high reputation and look at your own answers).

I've blocked those numbers using some browser extension, so now it looks for me like:
[image]

Just made the interface better. I didn't lose anything.

Comment: Blocking rep/badges may work for you, but it wouldn't work for everyone. I find reputation useful; for example, ~1 rep users aren't likely to do anything else on the site so I'll just edit their posts for them, while I more often leave comments on posts where the user has some rep telling them to fix something (so that maybe next time they don't have to be told).

Comment: @Laurel "1 rep users" = "New contributor" marker. Then, you can identify relatively new contributors by seeing only one brown dot and no silver or gold dot below the username (see the screenshot).

Comment: The new contributor banner disappears after a week so it’s not helpful for identifying old one-offs. It also shows up on people who have much more rep, either from the association bonus or from posting several good posts within the first week. Plus, that was only one example of many of how reputation is useful.